# Pandas create multiple dataframes by applying different weightings

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe with 3 columns and I want to add them together and test different weights.

I've written this code so far but I feel this might not be the best way:

```
weights = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]

for i in weights:
     for j in weights:
         for k in weights:

outname='outname'+str(i)+'TV'+str(j)+'BB'+str(k)+'TP'
df_media[['outname']]=df_media[['TP']].multiply(i)
+df_media[['TV']].multiply(j)
+df_media[['BB']].multiply(k)
```

Below is the input dataframe and the first output iteration of the loops. So all of the columns have been multiplied by 0.5.

df_media:

```
TV     BB    TP
1      2     6
11     4     5
4      4     3
```

Output DataFrame:

```
'Outname0.5TV0.5BB0.5TP'
       4.5
       10
       5.5
```

Comment: Please add a dataframe (with code to instantiate it) and the expected output for that sample. I'm ready to fire up the interpreter, but I can't be bothered to come up with a df that may not even look like your data on my own.

Comment: Thanks for the dataframe, but we also need what the final output should be.

Comment: @timgeb, Looks like OP has now added input & output.

Answer (score 0):

#### Dictionary

If you need a dataframe for each loop, you can use a dictionary. With this solution you also don't need to store your factor in your column name, since the weight can be your key. Here's one way via a dictionary comprehension:

```
weights = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]

col_name = '-'.join(df_media.columns)
dfs = {w: (df_media.sum(1) * w).to_frame(col_name) for w in weights}

print(dfs[0.5])

   TV-BB-TP
0       4.5
1      10.0
2       5.5
```

#### Single dataframe

Much more efficient is to store your result in a *single* dataframe. This removes the need for a Python-level loop.

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.sum(1).values[:, None] * np.array(weights),
                   columns=weights)

print(res)

    0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9   1.0
0   4.5   5.4   6.3   7.2   8.1   9.0
1  10.0  12.0  14.0  16.0  18.0  20.0
2   5.5   6.6   7.7   8.8   9.9  11.0
```

Then, for example, access the first weight as a series via `res[0.5]`.